# PHP take id's from one table and pull data that corresponds with those id's from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have this query:

```
$query = "SELECT *FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_isEvent' AND meta_value ='yes' ORDER BY post_id LIMIT 0, 5" or die(mysql_error()); 
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

        $eventid = $row ['post_id'];

    echo "<p>".$eventid."</p>";


    }
```

This currently posts some ids `$eventid`. I now want to run another query in another table (same database) that pulls some post titles that matches those id's.

Table is called "wp_posts" and column to match is "ID" and want to echo out post title from "post_title".

Where do I start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use SQL joins.  W3 schools has a good intro article about this.
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Something like the following

```
SELECT post_title FROM wp_postmeta m, wp_posts p WHERE m.wmeta_key = '_isEvent' AND m.meta_value ='yes' AND m.post_id == p.post_idORDER BY m.post_id LIMIT 0, 5
```

Comment: thank you, I had heard about join, but all the tutorials seemed really confusing, but the way you did it made alot of sense. thanks

Comment: here's my favorite article on JOINS:  http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/Understanding-SQL-Joins/